# iOS Keyboard pushing jQuery-confirm prompt view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, confirm

my web page shows a jquery confirm prompt view. And once the user selects the input field and the keyboard shows, the keyboard pushes the jquery confirm prompt view. The problem only happens on iOS device. Is there a work around to this?

Here is my code

```
$.confirm({
        title: 'Add Your Name Information',
        content: 'Please provide the ff<br/><br/>'+
    '<div class="form-row">'+     
      '<div class="form-group col-md-2">'+
        '<input type="number" id="age" class="form-control"  max="2" required>'+
        '<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="age">Age</label>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="form-group col-md-2">'+
        '<input type="number" id="contact" class="form-control"required>'+
        '<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="contact">Contact No</label>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div class="form-group col-md-8">'+
        '<input type="text" id="bldg" class="form-control" value="' + Name+ '" readonly="true">'+
        '<label class="form-control-placeholder" for="bldg">Name</label>'+
      '</div>'
    '</div>',
        buttons: {
           formSubmit: {
           text: 'Confirm',
           btnClass: 'btn-blue',
            action: function () {
           params += "&age=" + age
           params += "&contact=" +contact
              $.post( "/name/save", values)
                  .done(function( data ) {
                  data = JSON.parse(data);
                  }
              });
            }
                  },
            cancel: function () {
            }
        },
        columnClass: 'medium'
    });
  }
```